# Scraping <span>flow text</span> with BeautifulSoup and urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am working on scraping the data from a website using BeautifulSoup. For whatever reason, I cannot seem to find a way to get the text between span elements to print. Here is what I am running.

```
data = """ <div class="grouping">
     <div class="a1 left" style="width:20px;">Text</div>
     <div class="a2 left" style="width:30px;"><span 
     id="target_0">Data1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="a3 left" style="width:45px;"><span id="div_target_0">Data2
   </span></div>
   <div class="a4 left" style="width:32px;"><span id="reg_target_0">Data3
   </span</div>
</div>
"""
```

My ultimate goal would be to able to print a list ["Text", "Data1", "Data2"] for each entry. But right now I am having trouble getting python and urllib to produce any text between the . Here is what I am running:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://target.com'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

Search_List = [0,4,5] # list of Target IDs to scrape

for i in Search_List:
    h = str(i)
    root = 'target_' + h
    taggr = soup.find("span", { "id" : root })
    print taggr, ", ", taggr.text
```

When I use urllib it produces this:

```
<span id="target_0"></span>, 
<span id="target_4"></span>, 
<span id="target_5"></span>,
```

However, I also downloaded the html file, and when I parse the downloaded file it produces this output (the one that I want):

```
<span id="target_0">Data1</span>, Data1 
<span id="target_4">Data1</span>, Data1
<span id="target_5">Data1</span>, Data1
```

Can anyone explain to me why urllib doesn't produce the outcome?

Comment: give the real URL of site that you want to parse, please

Answer (score 2):

use this code :

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

your_data = list()

for line in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'id': 'target_0'}):
    your_data.append(line.text)


...
```

similarly add all `class attributes` which you need to extract data from and write `your_data` list in csv file. Hope this will help if this doesn't work out. let me know.

Comment: Thanks! That works for the first class (not in a <span></span>), but doesn't work in the other two. However, when I download the webpage to a .html file and parse that file, I don't have this problem. Do you have any thoughts on why that might be?

Otherwise, I suppose I could try parsing the div's children and going through there, right?

Comment: I updated the code, for the `data1` text. try this first  @Naruto

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to create your lists based on the source HTML you have shown:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """ 
<div class="grouping">
     <div class="a1 left" style="width:20px;">Text0</div>
     <div class="a2 left" style="width:30px;"><span id="target_0">Data1</span></div>
     <div class="a3 left" style="width:45px;"><span id="div_target_0">Data2</span></div>
     <div class="a4 left" style="width:32px;"><span id="reg_target_0">Data3</span></div>
</div>

<div class="grouping">
     <div class="a1 left" style="width:20px;">Text2</div>
     <div class="a2 left" style="width:30px;"><span id="target_2">Data1</span></div>
     <div class="a3 left" style="width:45px;"><span id="div_target_0">Data2</span></div>
     <div class="a4 left" style="width:32px;"><span id="reg_target_0">Data3</span></div>
</div>

<div class="grouping">
     <div class="a1 left" style="width:20px;">Text4</div>
     <div class="a2 left" style="width:30px;"><span id="target_4">Data1</span></div>
     <div class="a3 left" style="width:45px;"><span id="div_target_0">Data2</span></div>
     <div class="a4 left" style="width:32px;"><span id="reg_target_0">Data3</span></div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

search_ids = [0, 4, 5] # list of Target IDs to scrape

for i in search_ids:
    span = soup.find("span", id='target_{}'.format(i))

    if span:
        grouping = span.parent.parent
        print list(grouping.stripped_strings)[:-1]      # -1 to remove "Data3"
```

The example has been slightly modified to show it finding IDs `0` and `4`. This would display the following output:

```
[u'Text0', u'Data1', u'Data2']
[u'Text4', u'Data1', u'Data2']
```

Note, if the HTML you are getting back from your URL is different to that seen been viewing the source from your browser (i.e. the data you want is missing completely) then you will need to use a solution such as `selenium` to connect to your browser and extract the HTML. This is because in this case, the HTML is probably being generated locally via Javascript, and `urllib` does not have a Javascript processor.

Comment: Are there ways to check the HTML or CSS to determine whether the data are computed by javascript? Or do you need to see the JS?
I use Google Chrome inspect element to read the HTML/CSS. Is there a better app to inspect the elements? Like I said, the data comes up on "inspect element" AND when I downloaded the html file and parsed it with BS, but urllib seems unable to read it strait from the website.

Comment: If the HTML source you see in your browser does not match the source seen by printing what is returned by urllib or the requests library for example then it is probably Javascript. A selenium based solution would only add a few lines to your script.